# java 8 Docker Improperly specified VM option 'InitialRAMPercentage=XX'

Tags: java, scala, docker, kubernetes, java-8

When setting `InitialRAMPercentage` or `MaxRAMPercentage` on `graalvm-ce:19.2.0.1` (java 8u222) running in k8s I get `Improperly specified VM option 'InitialRAMPercentage=50'` running in k8s.

I'm setting the options as per [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u191-relnotes-5032181.html):

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
```

Answer (score 31):

Apparently this is a known bug see [JDK-8219312 : -XX:MaxRAMPercentage doesn't recognise integer number correctly](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8219312).

I solved this by changing my java options to:

```
-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0
```

Comment: Very quick answer ;) Great

Comment: @Alberto C Did you mean `80.0` like in your link workaround?  I don't see a difference between your question and your answer.

Comment: @Nexevis yes, apparently RAM Percentage settings do not like integer values

Comment: `80` works on macOS but doesn't work on linux. On linux you need `80.0`.That's so weird.